# JavaScript to reconnect/refresh/stay upon high load or about to timeout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-10

I need some help in here. I have a transition or 2 web page (aspx). The first page was to play video and after finish playing, it will be redirected to page 2 and then back again to page 1. The loop will continues 24/7 in smart TV via web browser.

I am having an issue where I will need to go grab the remote controller to refresh/reopen the web page whenever facing connection lost:

[image: connection lost]

or connection timeout:

[image: connection timeout]

I tried to fix this problem by adding some JavaScript to check the connection availability:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        if (Offline.state === 'up') {
            window.location.href = '../Slide/SlideshowLSI.aspx';
        }
        else {
            this.currentTime = 0;
            this.play();
        }

    }
</script>
```

What this code does is simply check the connection availability before the redirect to the next page. If it detects that the connection was not available then it will set the video play back to 0 and continue to play the video again. Then it will redirect to the next page after video playback is done and connection is available.

I think this will solve the issue regarding the lost connection problem but not for the connection timeout problem.

I am still facing an issue if a connection timeout occurs and I will need to grab the remote controller to refresh/reopen the web page again on each of the smart TV. I have total of 15 smart TVs currently opening these pages 24/7.

Anyone know how I can solve this problem regarding the connection timeout problem? I tried to search on the internet but all I get is just to check for connection lost problem. I need something that checks the response time before redirecting to the next page, so that I can avoid the connection timeout error page. If the response time were too long, the web page will not be redirected to the next one, but will keep on attempting and redirect to the next page when the response time is not too high that will not cause the connection timeout.

Sorry for my English. Do comment if my explanation was not complete... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JQuery you could simply fire off an AJAX request with a timeout and catch the success/error.

```
<script>
function ping(){
   $.ajax({
      url: '/Slide/SlideshowLSI.aspx',
      timeout: 3000,
      success: function(result){
         window.location.href = '../Slide/SlideshowLSI.aspx';
      },
      error: function(result){
          this.currentTime = 0;
          this.play();
      }
   });
}
```

Otherwise in plain Javascript something like this should work:

```
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/Slide/SlideshowLSI.aspx');
xhr.timeout = 4000; // Set timeout to 4 seconds
xhr.send(null);

xhr.ontimeout = function () {
    console.log("timed out");
}   

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === OK)
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // 'This is the returned text.'
    } else {
        console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro..I will give a try first.. By the way, this method will also work in Lan network/ Intranet? Sorry if my question may sound funny..

Comment: Nice..I am now trying to apply this...Does not work for me currently.. I think maybe I got something wrong or something missing..Not sure :(

Comment: Sorry again sir if I'm asking..If I wanted to achieve this.. I just get the Jquery file? Is that right? **<script src="../javascripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>** to header.

Comment: Yes, for the first option importing the Jquery min file should be fine.  You should get a success response from a successful page response or an error of some sort if the page can't load.  The 2nd option just uses vanilla javascript and JQuery is unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry again Sir Nathan, is there any specific Jquery that I should be using as I am using jquery-3.3.1.min.js and it is not working :(

Comment: It should work with basically any of them.  Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I am not getting any errors..Just nothing happen :(